# How can I use JQuery to populate multiple divs with content from external html page and update that content based on attributes on each div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two divs on a page that need be populated with the same block of code from an external html page. I am calling a separate api per div that should dynamically replace each variable in the external content block.

I am using .load() to get the external content, but how can i pass the api url parameter for each div since onload() only works on specific tags?

html:

```
<div onload="getCard('api_url',this.id)" id="api_div_1">Here</div>

<div onload="getCard('api_url2',this.id)" id="api_div_2">Here</div>
```

jquery:

```
function getCard(api_url, div_id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: api_url,
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            var cards = result;
            var card = cards['cards'][0];
            $("#" + div_id).load("https://external.html div.schumer-container");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: So you are wanting to load only part of a secondary page into the first page?

Comment: yes, i want to add the same code from another page into multiple divs on my main page. the html will be the same, but just the variables will change based on each divs api_url

Comment: Instead of fetching an entire html page to pick out a part of it, I would suggest extracting that fragment to it's own file that you can reference from both places.  jQuery isn't really intended to load an entire dom to find a particular fragment.  Not saying it cannot be done, but I'd say it's not the best approach.

Comment: okay, but that's not my issue. i can load that page fine. how can i pass the api_url of each div (which will be different everytime) to update the variables in the newly fetched html block.

Comment: if your backend is using some language like php or such, you can provide that request with the data it can use to build that page fragment.  otherwise if you want the fragment to return static markup that you then want to change, you can stick a fragment in $() and then manipulate it, before (or after) you attach that to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean something like this:
Simply store the api source as an attribute on the html element. Then you can loop over every element with javascript to call the api to populate it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $( "div" ).each(function( index ) {
  
    var apisrc = $(this).attr("data-apisrc"),
    $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
      url: apisrc,
      dataType: 'json',
      async: false,
      success: function(result) {
          $this.text(result); 
      error: function() {
          $this.text("content could not be loaded"); 
          //alert('error');
      }
    });

  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="api_div_1" data-apisrc="https://source1">Here</div>

<div id="api_div_2" data-apisrc="https://source2">Here</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! i have to tweak this a bit to get it to work for me, as my project is more complex than i originally thought, but this was the most helpful